# Identificar que um App está entrando em background

Tags: ios, mobile, swift, apple

Tenho um app que está em Object-C e estou tentando passar ele para Swift, mas estou com alguns problemas, um deles é o NSNotification que não está funcionando.

Em object-C, estou usando da seguinte forma:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"Entro em back");
}
```

Em swift estou tentando da seguinte forma, mas não esta chamando a função:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "applicationDidEnterBackground", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
 }

func applicationDidEnterBackground() {
    println("Entro em back")
}
```

No meu caso, preciso carregar uma informação no NSUserDefaults quando o app carregar e salvar as informações alteradas pela usuário quando o app entrar em background.

Obs: Não consigo acessar nenhuma das duas funções.

Comment: O código está funcionando perfeitamente. Provavelmente o seu View Controller que não está sendo instanciado corretamente. Verifique onde ele é instanciado.

Comment: Não é mais fácil utilizar os métodos de *delegate* do `AppDelegate`?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues não sei, é usual? O cara que me ensinou a 'programar' para IOS falava que não era comum fazer alterações no AppDelegate, tanto que no projeto em **Objective-C** tive que criar já a `NSNotification`

Comment: @RafaelLeão não estou com o código aqui, mas eu criei na ViewController que é criada como padrão no projeto. Ela está em branco ainda! rs

Comment: @DavidBatista bom, estes métodos estão no `AppDelegate` justamente para esta finalidade. Estão lá os dois que você precisa, tanto `applicationDidEnterBackground` quanto `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues agora a pergunta é... como acesso as informações da minha ViewController pelo 'AppDelegate'?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues Esses métodos só são interessantes em alguns casos, em outros as notificações se mostram mais interessantes.

Comment: @DavidBatista Só um friendly reminder: não use `NSUserDefaults` para coisas diferentes de preferências do usuário e configurações do App.

Comment: @fpg1503 desculpa, mas não entendi! ... No meu caso é para armazenar duas informações da tela ('String' / 'Int')... que o usuário pode alterar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade seu código por um detalhe está errado.

Perceba que o método `applicationDidEnterBackground:` tem um argumento e assim como no Objective-C, a partir do momento que seu método tem argumentos, você **deve** menciona-los no seletor separados por **:** para assinar o seletor corretamente, logo, seu código deve ficar assim:

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "applicationDidEnterBackground:", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)`

Perceba o : no fim da assinatura do método.

Espero ter ajudado.